# Cannot send message without a sender address :: Email by Gmail to reset password

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, email, reset

i just did this to get password reset mail, i have not added anything to controller or routes for this please suggest me the solution

Peoples are working and running it fine Using Default Auth in laravel 6

```
     ## .env ##

        '''
        MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
        MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
        MAIL_PORT=587
        MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
        MAIL_PASSWORD=djscsajhfslowhwo  //two step verified Password
        MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
        MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
        MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

        '''

    ## mail.php ##
```

Mail.php file Please Review this i have entered the two step vereification code in passwsord and have also updated using tls and all the thing are here .... But remember i haven't added anything to routes and controlller for this issue what should ypu suggest

```
    '''
    return [
        'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'from' => [
            'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'email@gmail.com'),
            'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'test'),
        ],
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',  

        'markdown' => [
            'theme' => 'default',

            'paths' => [
                resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
            ],
        ], 

        'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

    ];

    '''
```

Comment: Do you get `"530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. "` error?

Comment: two step verified Password will  not work on email  , you have to disable it  and also enable less secure in gmail account

Comment: @LalitKumar wrong you can get the application-specific password when you have 2FA enabled

Answer (score 0):

You need to read and follow the process in https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

It will guide you to creating an app-specific password this password effectively bypasses 2-factor authentication, so you should create a password for this and never use that password again so a Keylogger or scraper can never get it so they hackers don't have the ability to bypass your two-factor authentication.

The Mail From Address address should not be the textual value of "null", just set it to the email address your logging into Gmail with.